# Insert with React-Hook-Form

Tags: mysql, react-native, express, sequelize.js, react-hook-form

I have a modal with a React-Hook-Form that send data to my API and saves it in a MySql database, but when i click on the button, only 4 columns are filled('id', createdAt, updatedAt and user_id), and I have more 3 columns('title', 'description', 'photo').

```
export default function FeedModal() {
const [form, setForm] = useState([]);
const { register, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm();
const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    register({ title: 'title' });
    register({ description: 'description' })
}, [register]);

const onSubmit = async ({ title, description, photo }) => {
    const data = { title, description, photo };
    await api.post('/posts/1/create')
        .then(response => setForm(response(data)))
        .then(JSON.stringify(form))
        .catch(console.error());
    return () => handleSubmit(onSubmit);
}

const toogleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!isModalVisible);
}
```

My form:

```
            <View style={styles.Card}>
                <View style={styles.pubCard}>
                    <Text style={styles.intro}>Criar publicação</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        value={form.title}
                        name={'title'}
                        ref={register({ required: true })}
                        onChangeText={text => setValue("title", text, { shouldValidate: true })}
                        multiline={true}
                        style={styles.titleInput}
                        placeholder="Titulo">
                    </TextInput>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.btnView}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.upload} title="Selecionar Foto" >
                        <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontFamily: 'Montserrat_400Regular', textAlign: 'center' }}>Selecionar Foto</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.descView}>
                    <TextInput
                        value={form.description}
                        name={"description"}
                        ref={register({ required: true })}
                        onChangeText={text => setValue("description", text)}
                        multiline={true}
                        style={styles.descInput}
                        placeholder="Nos descreva com detalhes sobre o caso do seu Pet"></TextInput>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                <View style={styles.buttons}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={toogleModal} style={styles.ButtonClose}><Text style={{ color: 'white', fontFamily: 'Montserrat_400Regular' }}>Fechar</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} style={styles.ButtonClose}><Text style={{ color: 'white', fontFamily: 'Montserrat_400Regular' }}> Criar</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps `useFieldArray` will be the better usage here since you are talking about the insert.

`https://react-hook-form.com/api#useFieldArray`

you can then use the `insert` action. eg:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";

function App() {
  const { register, control, handleSubmit, reset, trigger, setError } = useForm({
    // defaultValues: {}; you can populate the fields by this attribute 
  });
  const { fields, append, prepend, remove, swap, move, insert } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "test"
  });
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(data))}>
      <ul>
        {fields.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <input
              name={`test[${index}].firstName`}
              ref={register()}
              defaultValue={item.firstName} // make sure to set up defaultValue
            />
            <Controller
              as={<input />}
              name={`test[${index}].lastName`}
              control={control}
              defaultValue={item.lastName} // make sure to set up defaultValue
            />
            <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>Delete</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => insert(1, { firstName: "appendBill", lastName: "appendLuo" })}
      >
        append
      </button>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```